# Excel VBA - Paste data in a specific format to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following data on Sheet1:

```
Column A    Column B<br/><br/>
AA          Google<br/>
BB          Google<br/>
CC          Amazon<br/>
DD          Amazon<br/>
EE          FB<br/>
FF          FB<br/>
```

I want the following result in Sheet2:

```
Column A<br/><br/>
Google<br/>
(one line break)<br/>
AA<br/>
BB<br/>
(one line break)<br/>
Amazon<br/>
(one line break)<br/>
CC<br/>
DD<br/>
(one line break)<br/>
FB<br/>
(one line break)<br/>
EE<br/>
FF<br/>
```

I have a very basic knowledge of VBA. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you click `edit` underneath your question and tidy up your sample data. I assume these linebreaks are not really data. Also, while you may have limited knowledge of VBA it's wise to at least include the code you have attempted and describe what part is not working as intended. Otherwise this question may come across as you asking us to do all the work for you. See [ask] a question with a [mcve]. And one question about your data..... would column B always be in order?

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stacked. SO is not a free coding service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I threw this sample code together quickly to get you started. You'll see that it gets you part of the way there, but needs help at the end. It's not elegant, but then, neither is your problem ;)

The main point is that you first set up suitable variables, and then by use of `range` and `offset` you can move around to put items at will on the sheet. If you step through the code with the debugger while observing Sheet2 you'll understand more.

```
Option Explicit
Sub format()
Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range
Set sh1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set sh2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set r1 = sh1.Range("A1")
Set r2 = sh2.Range("A1")
While r1 <> ""
    If r1.Offset(0, 1) = r1.Offset(1, 1) Then
        r2 = r1.Offset(0, 1)
        Set r2 = r2.Offset(1, 0)
        r2 = "(one line break)<br/>"
        Set r2 = r2.Offset(1, 0)
        r2 = r1 & "<br/>"
        Set r1 = r1.Offset(1, 0)
        Set r2 = r2.Offset(1, 0)
        r2 = r1 & "<br/>"
        Set r2 = r2.Offset(1, 0)
        r2 = "(one line break)<br/>"
        Set r1 = r1.Offset(1, 0)
    End If
Wend
End Sub
```